# What are the main differences between Jesusonians and Protestant christians?

Tags: protestantism, comparative-christianity

Both groups have much variation from the traditional beliefs. Also I just recently heard of the Jesusonian denomination.

What are the main differences between these two denominations?

Comment: A very brief search suggests this group is totally outside Christian norms, so contrasting them with the Apostle's creed or even more basic statement of Christian faith may be more appropriate. You may consider adding a basic statement of their beliefs to the question. The scope of this question will probably need to be narrowed considerably to make it work here. Welcome to Christianity.SE.

Comment: How recently did you hear about this denomination? You've been answering questions about it on this site for several weeks.

Comment: I heard it recently last year :D. I'm not good at asking specific questions so I'll be back when I'm able to subtly phrase a question that I "would at one and the same time challenge their teaching and suggest his own" like Jesus on his 3rd day at the temple.
- 125:5.8 Jesusonian Bible

Comment: As for the ‘Jesusonian Bible’ (Author Roger Crawford, published January 2017), one review observes “This book is nothing more than an extravagantly-priced duplication of the fourth section of the Urantia Book”.  Without access to same “Bible” it is impossible to challenge or compare teachings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a Wikipedia article, I understand that Jesusonians are associated with Urantia.  One major difference between them and Protestantism include a belief in soul sleep and annihilationism, similar to Seventh-Day Adventism.  Other differences include:

> Jesus' crucifixion is not considered an atonement for the sins of humanity. The crucifixion is taught to be an outcome of the fears of religious leaders of the day, who regarded his teachings as a threat to their positions of authority.
>
> Jesus is considered the human incarnation of "Michael of Nebadon," one of more than 700,000 "Paradise Sons" of God, or "Creator Sons." Jesus is not considered the second person of the Trinity as he is in Christianity. The book refers to the Eternal Son as the second person of the Trinity.
>
> Jesus was born on Earth through natural means of conception instead of a virgin birth.
>
> Jesus did not walk on water or perform some of the miracles that are attributed to him in the Bible.
>
> Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Urantia_Book#Comparison_to_Christianity

Here is a link to another article that may be relevant: https://urantia-association.org/2018/jesusonian-calling-go-third-mile/